# how to import previous commit of excel spreadsheet into nodeJS

Tags: node.js, excel, git

I have to create a solution that would allow version control for excel spreadsheet for my company.

What I had in my mind was to export the spreadsheet into a format where each line would represent a cell using `exceljs` and save them into a file then commit those files. Then create a UI that would show a `git diff` in a more excel-like way

But I found a project called `ExcelCompare` https://github.com/na-ka-na/ExcelCompare that shows difference of two excel binary files in a simple command. But to be able to use this tool, I have to be able to import the excel file from the previous commit into my server. I know `git show commit-serial:file.extension` shows the file on command but it does not work very well for xlsx because they are binaires.

One way of doing it would be just cloning the identical repository in another folder and comparing the files but surely there has to be a simple solution to import just a single file. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you need custom diff driver as described in [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

Comment: http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/git-diffing-excel-files.html

Comment: @max630 thanks so much can't believe I didn't crash into that website